# Adding elements to a vector until the user doesn't want to any more?

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
 int userInput = 0;
        vector<int> userVector;
        cout << "Input the numbers you would like in the vector. " << endl;
        bool flag = true

        while (flag == true)
        {
            cin >> userInput;
        }
```

What I'd like the program to do is, the user enters numbers to the vector until they're content with it. I was thinking the condition to stop the loop could be typing any character/ string, but for the sake of being concise with a vector perhaps it could be 'no,' 'quit,' or just 'n.' I'm also not sure of how to integrate the userInput into the vector.

Comment: That forehead smack every time I see something like `while (flag == true)` is getting painful.

Answer (score 2):

EOF was invented for this purpose. It takes place when the user types Ctrl+D (Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Windows), or when the end of the file was reached if the input was provided from a file. There is no need to make up some sentinel value.

```
while (cin >> userInput) {
   // ...
}
```

This loop will stop when the input ends, or when an extraction fails.

Comment: This is great, but it wouldn't be an option in a case where you would then want to prompt the user for something else afterward.

Comment: @FredLarson: Why's that? You can have two loops in a program that refer to `cin`, y'know... If you're worried about reaching the end of input, then needing more input, then that doesn't make much sense but you could reset the error flags if you don't mind breaking file input.

Comment: Indeed, seeing as this should probably be a function called like `prompt_numbers(std::vector<int>& result)` or similar

Comment: You can loop again on `cin` after you hit EOF?

Comment: @FredLarson: I don't see why not. `std::cin.clear();`

Comment: Huh! I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try a little different approach and get input in string form. It allows much more robust error handling, as well as allowing a terminating input value.

```
std::string userInput;
std::vector<int> userVector;
std::cout << "Input the numbers you would like in the vector (Q to quit). " << std::endl;

while (getline(cin, userInput))
{
    // Ignore blank lines
    if (userInput.empty())
        continue;

    if (userInput[0] == 'Q' || userInput[0] == 'q')
        break;

    try
    {
        userVector.push_back(stoi(userInput));
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument&)
    {
        std::cout << "That's not a valid number!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```